# Is there a CompareAndSet or Compare-and-swap (CAS) equivalent for REST APis?

Tags: rest, grpc

A situation:

Actor One: updates the value of X to 1.

Actor Two: Wants to ensure that the value of X is not changed by any other actor, and then update the value of X to say 2.

At the moment, even if Actor Two does a Get before Update, he cannot be sure another Actor did not update it. So, question is: Can REST API the way they are today, adopt a CAS operation?

Another question: does GRPC support it?

Comment: HTTP offers [conditional requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232) you can use to mimic optimistic locking

Comment: Thanks for that link, are there any existing examples of this?

Comment: [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Conditional_requests) summarised their usage and application. Further information can also be found by kindly asking your favorite search engine